# MySQL : Get count of rows containing name from different table, both tables are in relation

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables in my database, let's say t1 and t2.
There are 2 rows in both of them.
1s is id and 2nd is Name

```
Table t1:
Id.       Name
1.         abc
2.         def
3.         ghi

Table t2:
Id.     Name
1.       abc
2.       abc
3.       abc
4.       def
4.       def
```

Now , I need this type of output in MySQL

```
Total.        Name
3.                abc
2.                def
0.                ghi
```

I tried this so far

```
Select Count(*) as Total, Name 
from t1 Inner Join 
     t2 
Group By t2.Name 
Having t1.Name = t2.Name
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.  Please show what you have tried.

Comment: *Bit of a tip:* I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Please read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey, Gordon I tried this Select count(*) , t1.name from t1 inner join t2 group by t2.name having t1.name = t2.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.Id) as Total, t1.Name
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
ON t2.Name = t1.Name
GROUP BY t1.Name;
```

The same answer like Yogesh, but with the comma and caps correctly set.

regarding the SELECT you made

```
Select Count(*) as Total, Name 
from t1 Inner Join 
     t2 
Group By t2.Name 
Having t1.Name = t2.Name
```

here my 2 cents

1st.) as there are two tables with the same column you will receive ambiguous column error, so you have to write "t1.Name" instead of just "Name"

2nd.) with an INNER JOIN you select always and only the rows that exist in both tables linked with fields at the ON part of the join

3rd.) and the HAVING clause is not a appropriate way to link tables together, use just the complete JOIN syntax with the ON and the according fields

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do `LEFT JOIN` & aggregation :

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.id), as total t1.name
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.name = t1.name
GROUP BY t1.name;
```